# What are ways to bypass errors?

Tags: python, websocket

I have some code but it results in a error. Specifically, websockets.client.connect does not like "/ws" not one bit. This results in a "Negotiation Error: Unsupported Extension." I need it to run /ws as it is mandatory. Any ideas how I can except this error? Literally anything helps.

```
async def connect(self):
    uri = "wss://" + userPrincipalsResponse['streamerInfo']['streamerSocketUrl'] + "/ws"
    self.connection = await websockets.client.connect(uri)
    if self.connection.open:
        print("Connection established. Client correctly connected")
        return self.connection
```

Comment: It seems like you are asking us for a way to "just make it work", which is nonsense.

Comment: If /ws is mandatory and yet it doesn't work, then I don't see what can be done, short of contacting the owner of that socket and asking them to please add support for /ws.

Comment: What's the value of `userPrincipalsResponse['streamerInfo']['streamerSocketUrl']`? Can you `print()` it and share it with us? If you're still working with the TD Ameritrade API (as you indicated in your [now-deleted iteration of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69307779), an error using *extremely* similar code to the [provided sample code](https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/streaming-data) would largely indicate a configuration or environmental issue on your end. Without more info, it's not easily answerable.

Comment: @JohnGordon I was able to get to the next step after adding another parameter to websockets.client.connect

Comment: @esqew Woah, I didn't know deleted questions could be pulled up haha, but yeah I was able to get it working, just running into other issues which can easily be handled. Thanks a ton you two!

Comment: @CodeNoob During cursory research of the error message it appeared in Google’s cache - I was able to view it because I have over 10k reputation here. Tangentially, please consider providing a self-answer below to help others with the same issue as you.

Comment: @esqew Yeah of course, so essentially websockets.client.connect is a method which could take multiple parameters. https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/issues/1046 This was on github which a person was able to give two additions you can make which could aid with NegotiationError

Comment: @CodeNoob Sorry, I meant add an answer in the answers section below by selecting the “Post Answer” button below - it makes it much easier for others to see this way (comments sometimes are collapsed to save space).

Comment: @esqew thanks for bearing with me, pretty new to all of this!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

websockets.client.connect is a method which could take multiple parameters. [This was on github which a contributor was able to give two additions you can add to websockets.client.connect() which could aid with NegotiationError](http://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/issues/1046)

In my example, I made the addition "compression = None"

```
async def connect(self):
  uri = "wss://" + userPrincipalsResponse['streamerInfo']['streamerSocketUrl'] + "/ws"
  self.connection = await websockets.client.connect(uri, compression = None)

  if self.connection.open:
       print("Connection established. Client correctly connected")
       return self.connection
```